# How to run both react and django on https

Tags: reactjs, django, ssl, https

I had a react+django app. The react app was on http://my.domain.com, and it called the django app that is on http://my.domain.com:8000.

Now, I have installed an SSL certificate and changed the react app to run on https://my.domain.com. However, whenever it tries to call the django app on http://my.domain.com:8000, I get an error `Blocked loading mixed active content “http://my.domain.com:8000/auth/”`. This makes sense, because I really have mixed content: an https page (the react app) tries to call http (the django app).

On the other hand, if I change the API call to “https://my.domain.com:8000/auth/”, it does not work at all (it hangs).

How can I let django accept calls through SSL, so that I do not get these `mixed content` errors?

Answer (score -1):

In order to resolve the mixed content error and allow your Django app to accept calls through SSL, you need to configure Django to work with HTTPS. Here are the steps you can follow:

Make sure your Django app is running behind a web server like Nginx or Apache. This is necessary to handle SSL/TLS encryption.

Install an SSL certificate on your web server and configure it to work with your domain (e.g., my.domain.com). You can obtain an SSL certificate from a trusted certificate authority (CA) or use a free certificate from Let's Encrypt.

Update your web server configuration to include the SSL certificate and enable HTTPS. For example, in Nginx, you would typically modify the server block for your domain to include the SSL settings:

```
nginx
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name my.domain.com;

    ssl_certificate /path/to/ssl_certificate.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/ssl_certificate.key;

    # Other Nginx configuration directives...
}
```

Restart your web server to apply the changes.
Update your React app's API calls to use the HTTPS URL of your Django app, which should now be accessible via https://my.domain.com:8000/auth/. Make sure to update all relevant API endpoints throughout your React app.
Test your React app to confirm that it can successfully make HTTPS API calls to your Django app. The mixed content error should no longer occur because both the React app and the Django app are using HTTPS.
By following these steps and configuring your web server to use SSL/TLS encryption, you can ensure that your Django app accepts secure HTTPS connections, allowing your React app to communicate with it without any mixed content issues.

Comment: This is what I thoguht. But, as I said in the question, the links under `https://my.domain.com:8000/` do not work (though the links under `https://my.domain.com/` do work).